# Question on definition derivation for concave functions

Tags: real-analysis

I was looking into how the following definition was arrived at of concave functions (and related convex functions). I found the following derivation/justification and had an issue with one of the steps. I think it is ok, but wanted someone to weigh in on the issue. Thanks in advance!

Concave function definition:

$$
f((1−λ)a + λb)  ≥  (1 − λ)f(a) + λf(b)
$$

The author goes on to state the following:

Denote the height of the line segment from (a, f(a)) to (b, f(b)) at the point x by $h_{ab}(x)$. Then according to the definition, the function f is concave if and only if for every pair of numbers a and b with $x_1$ ≤ a ≤ $x_2$ and $x_1$ ≤ b ≤ $x_2$ we have:

$$
f(x) \ge h_{a,b}(x) \; for \; all \; x \; with \; a ≤ x ≤ b
$$

Now, every point x with a ≤ x ≤ b may be written as x = (1 − λ)a + λb, where λ is a real number from 0 to 1.

> The fact that $h_{a,b}$ is linear means that
>   $h_{a,b}$((1 − λ)a + λb) =     (1 − λ)$h_{a,b}$(a) + λ$h_{a,b}$(b)

Further, we have $h_{a,b}(a)$ = f(a) and $h_{a,b}$(b) = f(b) (the line segment coincides with the function at its endpoints), so
$h_{a,b}$((1 − λ)a + λb)    =  (1 − λ)$f(a)$ + λ$f(b)$.

On the part in yellow, where the author uses the fact that $h_{a,b}$ is linear. I agree the function is linear in the fact that the highest degree of the function would be 1 (since it is a line), but stating it as a linear transformation and using properties of a linear transformation isn't as clear. I believe it is a linear transformation if either the line intercepts the y-axis at 0 OR we shift the coordinate system to force the line to intercept the y-axis at 0. Is this a correct explanation?

If the y-intercept was 8, we could re-write all of our coordinates using the equation (0,8) -> (0,0). So we subtract 8 to all coordinates in our space to shift the origin to ensure our line has no y-intercept and is thus a linear transformation.

Thanks!

Comment: You are right, the author should have said affine. You take two real numbers $c$ and $d$ and consider the function $$\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\mapsto (1-\lambda)c+\lambda d.$$ This is linear iff $c=0$. You should remove the bounty if you can. It is not worthy it.

Comment: @Gio67 a bounty cannot be removed. You should post your comment as an answer (since it answers the question and to indicate that the question has been answered).

Comment: @Gio67, thanks for reviewing. would my method of shifting the coordinate system work in addition to the function u gave? would they be equivalent ways of defining a line that is a linear operator and not affine?

Comment: You mean that if you have an affine line, you can always shift the coordinate system to force the line to intercept the y-axis at 0. Sure.

Comment: my only concern was that i've simply changed the function too much in order to justify that i am still considering the same problem(here that is the convex definition derivation), if that makes sense. My hope was that it shouldnt matter what coordinate system we refer to, only that we can describe the same line in an affine way, or a linear operator way -- in that case the linear operator way would solve our problem and allow us to assume linear operator properties for the remaining of the proof...Thanks again @Gio67

Comment: as it seems ur suggested function only re wrote the function, my suggested solution actually changes the coordinate system. im hoping they are equivalent in terms of solutions to this particular problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of a concave function requires an inequality to hold for **all** applicable $x$, $a$, and $b$. While you could define a shifted version of $f$ such that some particular $h_{a,b}$ passes through the origin, you can't make every $h_{a,b}$ pass through the origin simultaneously. So that's probably not worth doing.

The good news is, you don't need to!

Although $h_{a,b}$ is not a [linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_transformation), it is an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation). Affine transformations are characterized by preserving [affine combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_combination), which are linear combinations whose weights sum to $1$. In particular, $(1 − \lambda)a + \lambda b$ is an affine combination of $a$ and $b$. So the fact that $h_{a,b}$ is an affine transformation really does justify that $h_{a,b}((1 − \lambda)a + \lambda b) = (1 − \lambda)h_{a,b}(a) + \lambda h_{a,b}(b)$. No shifting or playing with coordinates is necessary to make this work.

Comment: Thanks! Just quickly, i looked at the affine transformation link u gave and it seems to have properties “close” to that of a linear transformation like f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y) but the affine case uses a different function on the RHS and doesnt seem to address all the linear transformation properties we would need here. What am I missing?

Comment: When you say "all the linear transformation properties we would need here", can you give an example of a property that you need?

Comment: The author uses f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y). Then also for scalers f(cx) = cf(x) @ChrisCulter

Comment: Where does the author use f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)?

Comment: The yellow highlighted section in my original post

Comment: That equation does **not** rely on a claim that f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y) for all x and y.

Comment: Why in this case are “a” and “b” not equivalent to x and y?  If they are not equivalent, then what property allows the operation he does? Does it have something to do with a and b being the endpoints?

Comment: Do you agree with the following? (A) the expression $(1 − \lambda)a + \lambda b$ is an affine combination of $a$ and $b$. (B) $h_{a,b}$ is an affine transformation. (C) Affine transformations preserve affine combinations. (D) $h_{a,b}$ preserves affine combinations. Now what can we conclude about $h_{a,b}((1 − \lambda)a + \lambda b)$?

Comment: That it would preserve our affine combination! This whole thing was new to me on affine so looks like ill have to read up on them more. Thanks for the intro to them and help....so regarding the post do u think the author shouldve said affine transformation instead of linear?

Comment: (shrug) The reality is, sometimes people use "linear" to mean something other than linear transformations. Phrases like "linear regression" or "piecewise linear" are so widespread and ingrained, that you can't expect everyone to switch to saying "affine", as in "affine regression" or "piecewise affine". So I mean, yeah, it would have been more precise to say "affine transformation", but it isn't totally unreasonable for the author to say "linear" either.

Comment: Great, thanks Chris. Very helpful.